# Angular - Passing Array of Observables as @Input

Tags: javascript, html, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm trying a replace a current NGRX implmentation of binding data in template to reusable component due to change in dataStructure of @Input.

```
HTML:
//replace
"<child [summary]="summaryTitle$ | async" ></child >"

//with
"<child  [summary]="summaryTitles" ></child>"
```

```
parent.comp.ts
//replace
summaryTitle$ = this.store.select(Title)

//with
summaryTitles = [{title:summaryTitle$ , text: "someConstantValue"},...]
```

Here I need to resolve the summaryTitles array before passing it to the `<child>`, any easy method to do so like using async pipe for single result.

the Idea is to re-use the existing `<child>` without making much changes and I wont able to add any changes to the @store as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: If `text` is never an observable:

```
const result$ = combineLatest(
  summaryTitles.map(({ title, text }) => 
    title.pipe(map(title => ({ title, text })));
  )
);
```

---

[A minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with something like [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) would be good, it's a pain to reproduce ngrx state and all, but something like this should work:

```
import { of, map, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

const summaryTitles = [
  { title: of('1'), text: of('2') },
  { title: of('3'), text: of('4') }
];

const result$ = combineLatest(
  summaryTitles.map(({title, text}) =>
    combineLatest([title, text]).pipe(
      map(([title, text]) => ({ title, text }))
    )
  )
);

result$.subscribe(console.log);
```

You may want to change [`combineLatest`](https://v6.rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest) for [`forkJoin`](https://v6.rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) or [`zip`](https://v6.rxjs.dev/api/index/function/zip). The doc's [operator decision tree](https://v6.rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree) and [learnrxjs.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) are great for that.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-9gah4b?file=index.ts

Edit:
If the `text` field may be an observable or not, use [`isObservable`](https://v6.rxjs.dev/api/index/function/isObservable), for example:

```
const result$ = combineLatest(
  summaryTitles.map(({ title, text }) => {
    const text$ = isObservable(text) ? text : of(text);
    return combineLatest([title, text$]).pipe(
      map(([title, text]) => ({ title, text }))
    );
  })
);
```

But it may be easier to insure it's an observable somewhere else before that.

Side note: I noticed now in my stackblitz the final result, which shouold be an array, is an "indexed object" (`{ 0: 'foo', 1: 'bar' }`). When I try to manually transform it to an array in ways that work in terminal it remains an object . I'm assuming this is a quirk in stackblitz. Check what you get live.

Comment: thanks for the solution , im actually trying to replicate above with forkJOin as you have suggested but it acceptes only observable i believe cause some time the value could be constants```const summaryTitles = [
  { title: of('1'), text: 2 },
  { title: of('3'), text: 4 }
];```

Comment: @HARIPRASAD  I updated the response, please update the question. I assume you meant `text` _could_ be an observable but could also _not_ be? If it's never an observable it could be simplified

Comment: thnx a lot for all your scenarios !

Comment: considering one of the objects is nested in that case I can replace eg. text as { id: of('1'), desc: 'hello'} as well in above implementation as  ``` const result$ = combineLatest(
  summaryTitles.map(({ title, text:{id,desc}) => 
    combineLatest([title,{id}]).pipe(map(title => ({ title, text:{id,desc}})));
  )
); ```  -  can this work for nested object like  ``` summaryTitle = [{ title : obs1$ , text : {id : obs2$ , desc: 'hello'} } ] ``` or do i have to nest a level deeper with combineLatest ?

Comment: https://rxjs-hdq98y.stackblitz.io -- fork of above scenario

Comment: The stackblitz link you shared isn't working for me, but if I understood correctly the a `title` is an observable and  `text` is an abject that also has an observable `id` field. In that case you'll need to combine my first and last answers: use the map pipe for the text field, and combineLatest that observable with:`title`: `combineLatest(summaryTitles.map(({ title, text }) => combineLatest([title, text.id]).pipe(map(([title, id]) => ({ title, text: {...text, id }})))));`